# Listar todas las bases de datos de un servidor en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Intento obtener un pequeño reporte de SQL Server 2008.

Requiero listar todas las bases de datos creadas en el servidor, y que incluya:

- Nombre
- fecha creacion
- usuario (el que tiene permisos de db_owner)
- y tamaño

El `sp_helpdb` me otorga ciertos datos y no puedo unirlos con mi consulta:

```
SET language 'Spanish'
SELECT 
    name AS [Nombre DB]
    ,LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,crdate),10) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),crdate,105) AS [Fecha Creación] 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
order by crdate
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo realizarlo?

Comment: Tiene que ser en SQL? porque creo que si lo tratas de hacer usando sentencias SQL no vas a poder, conosco de otra forma pero es con c# o vb y usando objetos.

Comment: ¿Serviría para realizarlo en el vb de Excel? de ser así igual podria ser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esperando que tengas los permisos necesarios, usa:

```
DECLARE @databaseName sysname
   ,@databaseDate VARCHAR(50)
   ,@databaseSize NUMERIC(9, 3)
   ,@SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @CONSOLIDADO TABLE
(
    [Nombre] VARCHAR(100)
   ,[Usuario] VARCHAR(100)
   ,[Fecha Creacion] VARCHAR(50)
   ,[Tamaño MB] NUMERIC(9, 3)
);

DECLARE databaseCursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT name
   ,LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, create_date), 10) + ' '
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), create_date, 105)
   ,(
        SELECT SUM((size * 8) / 1024.00)
        FROM sys.master_files
        WHERE database_id = db.database_id
    )
FROM sys.databases db;

OPEN databaseCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM databaseCursor
INTO @databaseName
   ,@databaseDate
   ,@databaseSize;

WHILE (
          @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      )
BEGIN
    SET @SQL
        = N'SELECT ''' + @databaseName + '''
          ,p.name
          ,''' + @databaseDate + '''
          ,''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), @databaseSize) + '''
        FROM ' + @databaseName
          + '.sys.database_role_members m
        INNER JOIN ' + @databaseName
          + '.sys.database_principals p on m.member_principal_id = p.principal_id 
        WHERE 
            USER_NAME(role_principal_id) IN (''db_owner'')
            AND p.name NOT IN (''dbo'')';

    INSERT INTO @CONSOLIDADO
    EXEC(@SQL);
    FETCH NEXT FROM databaseCursor
    INTO @databaseName
       ,@databaseDate
       ,@databaseSize;

END;
CLOSE databaseCursor;
DEALLOCATE databaseCursor;

SELECT *
FROM @CONSOLIDADO;
```

Comment: Funcionó a la primera y de hecho es la respuesta correcta, solo me quedan 2 dudas. ¿el tamaño está en mb?, cuando muestra las bases, tambien muestra las de sistema, es posible filtrar que no muestre aquellas bases y ademas que no muestre las que tengan usuario "dbo" en especifico?

Comment: @EstebanJaramillo, el tamaño está en MB y solo era modificar la consulta interna para realizar algún filtro adicional.

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo, la verdad funciona como anillo al dedo! gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *FROM sys.databases 
SELECT * FROM [SYS].[COLUMNS] --Mostrar en columnas
SELECT * FROM [SYS].[TABLES] --Mostrar en tablas

--NOMBRE DE LAS BASES DE DATOS Y LA FECHA DE CREACIÓN-----

SELECT NAME AS [NOMBRE], 
CONVERT( VARCHAR(10),CRDATE,105) AS [FECH CREACIÓN]
FROM SYSDATABASES
ORDER BY CRDATE
```

Comment: ¿Qué puede aprender el OP de esta respuesta? ¿Qué enseñanza puede sacar que le evite problemas a futuro? ¿Cual fue el error cometido? ¿Cómo soluciona este código dicho error?